# View Contents of "Sheet" in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I am in the midst of converting an amazing made-with-excel "application" coded entirely with VBA.

In one of the .xls file, and in its first Sheet "input", it has a bunch of dropdown boxes. selecting one of these dropdownbox will show in the formula bar:

```
=Calcs!$H$15
```

Now, the issue is that there is only one visible worksheet in the .xls at the beginning, and even after I unhide Sheet, only one other Sheet "report" appears.

But if I go into developer VBA mode, I can see the "Calc" sheet in the VBA Project panel, along with the "input" and "report" sheet, and also many other sheets that are not visible via unhide Sheet. But in VBA, the contents of these sheet is all empty (ie. there is no code in the sheets).

Now, my question is, how can I view the contents of Calc sheet and the rest? To see the cell values for the dropdownbox, and also other things?

Comment: In the properties of the Calc sheet (as viewed from the VBA editor) is the "Visible" property set to xlSheetVeryHidden?

Comment: @Jelly That's right! Thanks. Make your response as answer and i will mark it as Answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help! I couldn't remember off the top of my head if that's what "very hidden" meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sheet property "Visible" is set to xlSheetVeryHidden it will not show up in the list of hidden sheets. Change the property to either xlSheetHidden or xlSheetVisible in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

To make it appear, do as follows:

- Double click the sheet within VBA
- Open 'properties' (shortcut is F4)
- Change the last property *-1 xlSheetvisible*

Rgds

**Edit:** Ups, already answered, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.